# How to get logits from Tensorflow pertained model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm following the tutorial of Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection
My model loaded like this, same as tutorial

`model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))`

However, the output put of the model is like this:

`{'num_detections': tf.float32, 'detection_scores': tf.float32, 'detection_classes': tf.float32, 'detection_boxes': tf.float32}`

I want to run some postprocessing on the original logits, how can I get them?

Link to tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: please, post the link of the tutorial

Comment: Link to tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb